# form POST data array isn't posting into the php

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

This is some HTML code i have that echos from the A php file. I am Posting the data as an array, but when i read the array no data seems to pass to the B php file.

```
<form method="POST" id="Insert" action="Insert.php">
    <div>
        <div>
            Trans# : 
        <input 
        type="text" name="Out[]" value="'.$row['TransNum'].' "readonly
        >
        </div>

        <div>
            Date : 
        <input 
        type="text" name="Out[]" value="'.$row['Date'].'"
        >
        </div>

        <div>
            To / From : 
        <input 
        type="text" name="Out[]" value="'.$row['ToWhere'].'"
        >
        </div>

        <div>
            Amount : $
        <input 
        type="text" name="Out[]" value="'.$row['Amount'].'"
        >
        </div>

        <div>
        <input 
        type="submit" 
        value="UPDATE"
        name="SUBMIT"
        >
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

And here is the php code.

```
if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT']))
{
    $PostData = $_POST['Out'];
    implode(", ", $PostData);
    $TransNum = $_PostData[0];
    $Date = $_PostData[1];
    $ToFrom = $_PostData[2];
    $Amount = $_PostData[3];
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "Account";
    $lnfd = "<BR>";
    $HTMLOut = "";
    $HTMLOut .= "Data Should be Here ->".$TransNum.$Date.$ToFrom.$Amount;
    echo $HTMLOut.$lnfd;
    $TableName = "Transfer";
}
```

I have looked over the code several times and googled the hell out of it, but i cannot figure out why

```
$Date, $ToFrom, $Amount,  $servername
```

are all printing blank in the php.

Comment: What does `$_POST['Out']` output as? This `implode(", ", $PostData);` is doing nothing, you aren't setting the return.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you store the data you `implode` anywhere.

Comment: `$_POST['Out']` is outputting data from a table (`$row['Amount']`) ect... @chris85

Comment: So `$_POST['Out'][0]` is set? Then `$_PostData[0]` should also be set. Wherever you are expecting a CSL you aren't going to have it, because you aren't setting the `implode`.

Comment: what exactly does implode do

Comment: When in doubt look at the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php. It turns an array into a string, separated by whatever it is told to use (in this case a `,`). You need to assign the value it returns to a variable though.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this

```
implode(", ", $PostData);
```

implodes into nothing, while this

```
$string = implode(", ", $PostData);
```

will put the result of the `implode` somewhere you can make us of it